# Can I use the Java Time Library to Convert Julian Dates Containing Both Date and Time?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, julian-date

I am trying to update legacy astronomical Java code to use the Java time library. The legacy code uses Date/Calendar/Gregorian Calendar/Time Zone, and a Julian Day library.

I would like to convert Julian Dates in UTC (e.g. 2458808.343055) to "local" date/time + UTC offset (to avoid Time Zones and DST rules), to find when they match (to the second).

As I understand it, Threeten-Extra supports Julian Day Numbers (date) only, but not the fractional part (time-of-day), so I guess I'll have to stick with a separate Julian Day library that handles these.

Is that correct?

Comment: IMHO, your Julian Date is probably what astronomers use. My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) has powerful support for it, see the class [JulianDay](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/astro/JulianDay.html). It even supports different flavors, also Julian Days on TT-scale (what is used by astronomers).

Answer (score 1):

I have used your example Julian Date (2458808.343055) and compared two different versions of [Julian days](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/astro/JulianDay.html) using my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J):

```
    double input = 2458808.343055;
    JulianDay jd = JulianDay.ofEphemerisTime(input); // used by astronomers
    System.out.println(jd.toMoment().toZonalTimestamp(ZonalOffset.UTC).toTemporalAccessor());
    // output of LocalDateTime: 2019-11-20T20:12:50.767995849

    JulianDay jdSimple = JulianDay.ofSimplifiedTime(input); // naive approach
    System.out.println(jdSimple.toMoment().toZonalTimestamp(ZonalOffset.UTC).toTemporalAccessor());
    // output of LocalDateTime: 2019-11-20T20:13:59.951995849
```

The difference is more than a full minute. Supporting the TT-scale (Ephemeris time) requires support for leap second handling which is only available in Time4J but not in standard Java. See also the [official definition of Julian days by IAU](https://www.iau.org/static/resolutions/IAU1997_French.pdf) (page 7).

*Side note: Calling `toTemporalAccessor()` can be left out unless you want to get an object of type `LocalDateTime` to satisfy your interfaces.*

Comment: Just curious, have there been 69 leap seconds already, or is the explanation longer than that?

Comment: @OleV.V. Not 69 but 27 leap secs. However, the Ephemeris time uses TT (terrestrial time). The relationship between TT and TAI can be expressed by: `TT = TAI + 32,184s`. In addition, you have to add 10 secs offset between TAI and UTC. Finally: `27 + 32.184 + 10 = 69.184` (the observed delta above).

Comment: This of course assumes that the *"legacy astronomical Java code"* used by OP is doing leap second adjustments too. Since question doesn't show what date and time is expected from the shown Julian value, it is difficult to be certain what algorithm was being used.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know the legacy astronomical Java Code of OP, too. But all serious astronomical calculations and data usually use the TT-scale (i.e. Ephemeris time). Using the formula and data of astronomy does not require the handling of leap secs. Leap secs are just used in a consecutive step to convert the results of the astronomical calculations to civil time (if people want or need high precision)..

Comment: @Meno The data is astronomical, but I didn't generate it myself. The anticipated date in UTC from the Julian 2458808.343055 example would be 2019-11-20 20:13:59.95 based on the JPL Time Converter here: [link](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tc.cgi#top). I am trying to convert these to civil time. I am only using accuracy to the minute or second.

Comment: @Menu I don't know what algorithm was used to calculate the Julian dates, but I'll try to find out if leap seconds were included in the calcs.

Comment: @JerseyP The website you refer to uses Julian Days on the scale UT (please pay attention to the letters "UT" after the input field!). So that converter expects JulianDay(UT) instead of JulianDay(TT). My lib Time4J also supports that variant. Just use `JulianDay.ofMeanSolarTime(double)`. It will yield similar results like `JulianDay.ofSimplifiedTime(double)` (not yet tested by me). Latter one can also be used if high precision is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE*** Code fixed to adjust for Julian dates with times starting at noon, and for millisecond precision.

For Julian date support, you need to add the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, which has the [`JulianChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/JulianChronology.html) implementation.

You can then do it like this:

```
double julianDay = 2458808.343055;

JulianDate julianDate = JulianDate.now().with(JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY, (long) (julianDay + .5));
LocalTime julianTime = LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(Math.round((julianDay + .5) % 1 * 8.64e7) * 1000000);
Instant instant = julianDate.atTime(julianTime).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
OffsetDateTime localDateTimeWithOffset = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime();

System.out.println(julianDate);
System.out.println(julianTime);
System.out.println(instant);
System.out.println(localDateTimeWithOffset);
```

*Output*

```
Julian AD 2019-11-07
20:13:59.952
2019-11-20T20:13:59.952Z
2019-11-20T15:13:59.952-05:00
```

The last value is because I'm in the US Eastern time zone.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Why does the julianDate show "AD 2019-11-07" in the first line of the output? I expected it would be "AD 2019-11-20", although the "instant" result in your output looks correct.

Comment: @JerseyP Because that day is Nov. 20 in the Gregorian calendar, but would be Nov. 7 in the Julian calendar, because of leap year shifts. The inaccurate leap year handling of the Julian calendar is why it was replaced by the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Well, one tricky correction is still missing, see my answer. I would rather expect the value: 2019-11-20T20:12:50.768Z instead of 2019-11-20T20:13:59.952Z